# How can I set a variable into ng-repeat from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I have this variable in my Controller:

```
$scope.numeroDescontos = 5;
```

I have one button that iterate the variable, and I want to build one 'ng-repeat' using that.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `ngRepeat` works over an Array - so you can have a function that'll take that number and return an array of that length - then repeat over that:

```
$scope.makeArray = function(num) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Then the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="num in makeArray(numeroDescontos)">Row {{num + 1}}</div>
```

Comment: What you have there is a slim [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Angular's built-in [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter? This filter creates a new array or string containing only a specified number of elements.

You can use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: numberOfElements">
```